# Building Issue after updating XAMARIN Forms for 2.2.045

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have updated `XAMARIN.Forms for 2.2.0.45`. I have used PCL approach. My Application is for iOS and Android only. Application is being build for iOS and PCL projects, but not for Android project. While building `Android`, in output window its just print

> 1>------ Build started: Project: myApp.Droid, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

and thats it, no further improvement in building process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible workarounds as in the thread https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36185

1)
 - Delete your .vs folder located in your solution folder

2)
 - Close all VS instances
 - Open the project in Xamarin Studio
 - Build your project there
 - After it builds successfully close Xamarin Studio.
 - Open the project in Visual Studio and build.

**The first one is much easier but takes a while to complete the build.**